# Add Roles in IdentityServer Response object

Tags: asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, identityserver3, user-roles, authorize-attribute

I'm using an Identity Server 3. I'm getting the Bearer Token from the IdentityServer3 only if the user has privilege otherwise return back as Un-Authorized.

De-Coded version of AccessToken is

```
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:1234/core",
  "aud": "https://localhost:1234/core/resources",
  "exp": 1489060441,
  "nbf": 1489056841,
  "client_id": "app1",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "roles",
    "app1"
  ],
  "sub": "93f7aab4-5469-4c85-8e73-5dcd859ed2a8",
  "auth_time": 1489056776,
  "idp": "idsrv",
  "amr": [
    "password"
  ]
}
```

My Expectation is

```
{
  "iss": "https://localhost:1234/core",
  "aud": "https://localhost:1234/core/resources",
  "exp": 1489060441,
  "nbf": 1489056841,
  "client_id": "app1",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "roles",
    "app1"
  ],
  "roles": [
    "Admin"
  ],
  "sub": "93f7aab4-5469-4c85-8e73-5dcd859ed2a8",
  "auth_time": 1489056776,
  "idp": "idsrv",
  "amr": [
    "password"
  ]
}
```

Client:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = @"APP1",
                ClientName = @"APP Implicit Client",
                Enabled = true,
                Flow = Flows.Implicit,
                RequireConsent = true,
                AllowRememberConsent = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:5775/callback/"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:5775/logout"},
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>{ "http://localhost:5775/" },
                AllowedScopes =
                    new List<string>
                    {
                        Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        Constants.StandardScopes.Email,
                        Constants.StandardScopes.Roles,
                        "app1"
                    },
                AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt
            }
```

User:

```
new InMemoryUser
            {
                Username = "User1",
                Password = "Password123!",
                Subject = "1",
                Claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName, "Bala"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName, "Balamanigandan"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, "balamanigandan.b@gmail.com"),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")
                }
            }
```

My WebAPI has a method with the following decoration `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]`, which needs the Bearer token of Role "**Admin**"

Kindly assist me how to add a Role in this Token to access the `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` methods in WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

try setting Scope called "Roles" and ScopeClaim called "Admin" and make ScopeTypeas "Resource" if you want that in "access_token" and i see you already have claims user claims as "Role" change that as "Roles"

Example Scope

```
 public static Scope Roles
    {
        get
        {
            return new Scope
            {
                Name = "Roles",
                Type = ScopeType.Resource,
                Emphasize = true,
                IncludeAllClaimsForUser = true,
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim> 
                {
                    new ScopeClaim("Admin",true)
                }
            };
        }
    }
```